# React Native: как собрать apk?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, build

Как правильно собрать apk из react native? Я нашел вариант с [expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html). Но apk чего-то не появляется:

- npm install -g exp
- Сделал app.json
- exp start exp build:android
- Появилась ссылка. Где брать apk?

Что я делаю не так? Как вы собираете react native?

Comment: А чем родной метод сборки плох? Gradle: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: Я не пойму в нем где брать файл ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: Согласно документации Gradle: "gradle.properties file in the Gradle user home directory (defined by the “GRADLE_USER_HOME” environment variable, which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle)" https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Так это же штука по сборке java, как ее нужно использовать с react native?

Comment: Эта штука по сборке чего угодно, хоть кулинарных рецептов :)

Answer (score 1):

генерируешь ключ, получаешь my-release-key.keystore,  его в папку android/app, правишь build.gradle с твоими параметрами:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

потом android$./gradlew assembleRelease и будет тебе счастье по маршруту:
 android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk